# QT Creator is not auto-detecting MSVC2017 64 bit compiler

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

I have Qt creator 4.6.0 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installed on my system.  Through Visual Studio, I have installed "Desktop development with C++" including VC++ 2017 v141 tool set.

When trying to configure the MSVC 2017 64 Kit in Qt Creator, the MSVC compiler is not auto-detected.  The only compilers that show are MinGw and Visual Studio 2008 (9.0) I believe I should be seeing "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 15.0".

Does anyone know how I can get the compiler to auto detect or add this manually.  I can compile and build QT programs in Visual Studio, but would like to use QT Creator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried installing/reinstalling to no avail.  I suspect there is an issue with my Visual Studio setup, but I have no clue what it could be.

Comment: There's no issue with your Visual Studio setup. Qt Creator's compiler detection is not complete. You'll need to build your own copy of Qt Creator and fix it in the sources, and ideally submit a patch to Qt Project.

Comment: Unbelievable that this is still not working in Dec 2018, when VS 2017 is over 1.5 years old and VS 2019 is approaching.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add it manually then. In the Build & Run settings, compiler tab, click add, custom -> C++, then fill the compiler line with the compiler's path.

But you have to fill correctly the ABI line, and if it doesn't fit any Qt build you already made, then you will have to build Qt from source again from a msvc command prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It would be helpful if you could provide the compiler path, make, path, and ABI information.  Currently I am pointing my compiler to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe.

Comment: A screenshot would be most helpful if anyone has been able to set this up manually...

Comment: Adding it manually would look like this:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iMNzWF3SECj-DSL1sRMlHH0yBBzqLYOH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i posted my last comment accidentally and can't edit it..
->

But I can't know precisely your ABI, you need to look in visual studio settings for that. All I can tell from your path is that it would be a 64 bits compiler... And I don't know which options are available for the ABI under windows. I guess visual studio should be there.
Make path points to make.exe, and for C++ compiler *should* be g++.exe.
Once you've added your custom compiler you also need to rebuild Qt with it from the source, and manually...

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem before. Then I install the [BuildTools for 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools) as well. And now it works very well.

Maybe you can refer these:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/97693/qt-creator-4-8-not-detecting-vs-2017-in-kits

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17925?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, it got it working by installing Visual Studio 2017 with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) like this:

```
choco install visualstudio2017community
choco install visualstudio2017-workload-nativedesktop
```

And after that Qt Creator 4.9 could detect the MSVC2017 compiler without issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
REM *************************************************************************
REM ** SETTING DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT
REM ** - Visual Studio
REM ** - Qt
REM *************************************************************************

D:
cd \svn\trunk
call C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qtenv2.bat
cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

You can't manually add MSVC to Qt Creator. If you want to use it make sure to have the correct Visual Studio version installed.

Try reinstalling Visual Studio if the MSVC compiler don't appear in the Compilers tab.

Comment: Ofc you can, add whatever compiler you wish in the "Compilers" tab. Add whatever qmake you wish in the tab "Qt Versions" and combine them however you want in the "Kits" tab.